# Почему выдает ошибку invalid syntax?

Tags: python

Вот собственно код, при его запуске выдаёт ошибку invalid syntax:

```
a=1

if a=1:
    a=0

print(a)
```

Питон начал изучать недавно, буду рад если объясните в чём ошибка.

Comment: В следущий раз читай всё сообщение об ошибке целиком, там всегда указано место, в котором ошибка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один знак "=" является оператором присваивания, Два знака "==" означает оператор сравнения.
В твоём коде в строке "if a=1:" ты используешь оператор присваивания, когда нужно использовать оператор сравнения.
Почитай - http://pythonicway.com/python-operators